# Query Cost based on Clustered Index

Tags: sql-server

In `Table1`, a clustered index is created on `C1` and `C2` columns. With this indices created, the cost for the two queries render the same value.

Query 1: `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE C1= 1 AND C2= 2`

Query 2: `SELECT C1, C2 FROM Table1 WHERE  C2 = 2 AND C1 = 1`

I would like an explanation on why the cost for the two queries is the same here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the complete table structure in your post? (+ possibly your execution plans)

Comment: If there isn't a great deal of data, the query plan will not need to use an index. You need to provide the execution plan for a definite answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a CLUSTERED index, so it's leaf level contain ALL the data, so it will be index seek in any case and there is no need to do any lookup: all the data is just there. At this point it does not matter if you want 1 column, 2,3 or all